# Can someone help me with an apex Trigger? "Invalid bind expression type of Contact for column of type Boolean"

Tags: trigger

here is the problem. I'm getting a error line called "Invalid bind expression type of Contact for column of type Boolean" with this trigger.

What I'm trying to do is: get a boolean value from the field "Check_Card__c" from Contacts and record it on the "All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c" field present in Accounts object.

This trigger must be enabled everytime I update a credit card field in Contacts. So the "Check_Card__c" will verify the number using Luhn Algorithm. If all the Contacts credit cards are valid, the checkbox must be enabled, if don't, so disabled.

The Luhn Algorithm is working properly and que "Check_Card__c" field as well.

Also, both "Check_Card__c" and "All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c" are checkboxes.

Maybe the solution is very easy, but I have not so much knowledge about triggers and the salesforce as well. I've tried a lot of alternatives, but no success yet.

Thank you guys

```
trigger CheckCardTrue on Contact (after update, after insert, after delete) {

    Contact c;
    
    for(Account a: [SELECT All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c FROM Account WHERE All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c IN: Trigger.New]){
        if(c.Check_Card__c == true){
            a.All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c = c.Check_Card__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Trigger.New` is a Contact List. In your SOQL you are passing this Contact List list instead of `All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c` List.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to query the contacts to find out if there are any invalid credit cards, and if not, check the flag as appropriate. As I wrote a number of years ago, you'll want to remember the [Aggregate-Query-Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern in Salesforce, as you'll use it many times.

```
// Aggregate data to query
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
// Check both old and new, since records can move accounts.
if(Trigger.new != null) {
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
  }
}
if(Trigger.old != null) {
  for(Contact record: Trigger.old) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
  }
}
accountIds.remove(null); // ignore private contacts
Set<Id> accountsWithInvalidCards = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
  SELECT AccountId Id 
  FROM Contact 
  WHERE Check_Card__c = false AND AccountId = :accountIds
  GROUP BY AccountId
]).keySet();
// Update
Account[] updatedAccounts = new Account[0];
for(Id accountId: accountIds) {
  updates.add(
    new Account(
      Id=accountId, 
      All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c=!accountsWithInvalidCards.contains(accountId)
    )
  );
}
update updatedAccounts;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your solution and it should be working, but I got a error code called "Invalid initializer type List<Contact> found for Map<Id,AggregateResult>: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List".

The keyset() method should solve this, no? But is not working.

Comment: @GabrielPiccolo Actually, that was my fault, it's still early in the morning. It just needed a GROUP BY in the SOQL.

Comment: oh I see, the error message disappeared. However, the check box "All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c" isn't been enabled. The trigger seems to be working, the field is getting que boolean value, but nothing happens to the checkbox. Maybe I created the wrong custom field. Should it be a checkbox by formula field, or a simple checkbox is enough? I don't understand why is not working :(

Comment: @GabrielPiccolo it must not be a formula, as they are not editable, and existing records won't be updated until the next time a contact is edited.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I was wondering about that. The only reason I created the checkbox "Check_Card__c" is because it's a checkbox from a formula field, where the Luhn Algorithm is working receiving the credit card record from another field in Contact. So the another checkbox present in Account should get this verification as well. Maybe I should use the Luhn Algorithm inside the trigger, I don't know. This assigment has been very difficult for me haha